# Can an imaginary sequence be produced to ease the equation of general term of a series whose common difference is in an AP

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I came across a problem which follows the series: **$2,3,6,11,18$** and so on..

It can be observed that the common difference of the series was in an arithmetic progression..

Using the regular method of supposing the general term as **$an^2+bn+c$** and plugging in the values $n=1,2,3$ for the first, second and third term of the series respectively, I got the equation **$n^2-2n+3$**..

For $n=0$, the zeroth term (which doesn't exist for a definite sequence) would give the value 3 from the above derived equation...

If the common difference (AP series) is extended backwards, the previous number in the indefinite series of the above given series will be 3 which basically is the zeroth term, and the previous common difference being $-1...$

**Is this a special case or can I always extend the series backwards and put $n=0$ for a series for a faster calculation of *c* thereby giving a faster calculation of the equation of the first term instead of solving 3 equations in 3 variables?**

Comment: If you start the sequence at index $n = 0$ instead of index $n=1$ like you chose, then you don't need to back down to find $c$. It will just be $2$. You will also find a nicer polynomial expression for the sequence. But that niceness was coincidental, it will always be true that $c$ is the $n = 0$ value, and thus the first element if you start the indexing at $0$. But the simpler polynomial this gives is due to the arithmetic sequence of differences happening to change signs at the first entry of the given sequence.

Comment: @PaulSinclair so in that case if I take a lets suppose non negative common difference, the expression I obtain for this case using n=0 would not follow the sequence?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "follow the sequence". If the sequence elements are given by a degree-2 polynomial, then the second differences (first difference is the sequence obtained by taking the differences of adjacent entries; second difference is the first difference of the sequence of first differences) will be constant - the same value for every entry, which means the first difference is an arithmetic sequence with that common difference, whether positive or negative. This true no matter where you start the indexing.

Comment: @PaulSinclair by follow the sequence, I meant satisfying all the terms of the series, also thanks I got the equations by taking a few more random examples..

Comment: I'm sorry, but explaining one meaningless phrase by using another meaningless phrase doesn't clarify anything. What do you mean by "satisfying all the terms of the series"? A sequence (we generally only use "series" if we are summing them up - but you are not the only one do otherwise) is just an ordered collection of numbers. How does one "satisfy" a number?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I meant that when you put n=1 it gives the corresponding first term, n=2 gives the second term and so on.

Comment: If you do the math right, the expression you obtain will provide the sequence, no matter where you start the indexing (i.e., which sequence member corresponds to $n=0$ or $n=1$). You will just get a different expression depending on where the index starts. You are correct that you can continue the sequence to the left as well as to the right (at least for sequences expressible by polynomials or similar functions). If $u_n = an^2 + bn + c$, then if you shift the indexing by $m$, you get $v_n = u_{n+m} = an^2 +(2am + b)n + (am^2 + bm +c)$, still a 2nd-degree polynomial.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Alright. Thanks, this just makes me wonder how we shift graphs in calculus a similar shifting of terms can be done in the sequence, like its something all too beautiful..

Comment: You replace $x$ with $x+m$ to shift the graph $m$ units to the left. You add $m$ to the function to shift the graph $m$ units up. The first ix exactly what I did to the sequence.